# Are Resplendent Chests worth farming?

Tags: diablo-iii

You can often find Resplendent Chests in the bottom of optional dungeons, and sometimes randomly on the field. Are these chests worth constantly looking for, or is there a cap to the types of items they can drop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer appears to be yes, but with caveats.

There are a number of references to farming Resplendent Chests (I don't personally, so I can't speak from experience) and they generally concede it is worth it *in Inferno, if you can't kill Champion or Rare packs*.  The implication is that the Rare and Champion packs are a more efficient way of getting good items, but [some Resplendent Chests are easily accessible](http://www.diablofans.com/topic/42678-revealing-this-trick-so-blizzard-can-fix-it-easily-farmed-resplendent-chest/) so can provide a good way of bootstrapping your own items/gold to compete in Inferno.