# Is chest farming worth it?

Tags: diablo-iii

I saw this forum post:
http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/12329613230

The gist of the rather long post is that you get far more legendaries by making "chest runs" through story missions, like Act V Mission 6.2, than you will by killing anything. It recommends stacking survivability and mobility and **outright ignoring** all mobs (especially elites) and treasure goblins, focusing solely on looting chests. The results it claims are on the order of 6 legendaries/hr as opposed to approximately 1.7 legendaries/hr playing the game "normally".

Some people in the thread says it's fake. I want to know if chest farming like this is worth it in any way.

Comment: That's an awful long post.  Why don't you summarize what it is you're after, since different people can take away different things from it?

Comment: See also: [Are Resplendent Chests worth farming?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67812/are-resplendent-chests-worth-farming?rq=1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Chest farming has always been worth it, that's why almost every chest loot route has been nerfed. I used to do it from time to time and let me tell you one thing : your brain will melt from how boring and repetitive it is. You will notice after 30 min of running how pointless it feels to "play" this way. I would rather clear rifts and spend bloodshard to increase my legendary drop rate than ever do Chest farming again. Plus 1,7leg/hour is if you are really unlucky. I usually get 1 leg per rift (all level cleared) which makes about 1 leg per ~15min then you have the bloodshard so you can easily reach 4-5 Leg/hour withtout Chest farming.

If I had to Chestrun I would go in Adventure Mode > Act V > Fortress of pandemonium lvl 2 (road before Malthael). There are between 6 and 8 chests and the area is pretty straightforward once you've spotted where are the portal on the map. With my Demon Hunter it takes no more than 2 min to get all chests and reset so I'd farm here.

Comment: Add one or more places where it would more profitable than rifts in your opinion or from your experience and you get the approved answer.

Comment: I don't know if chest runs are worth it now that you can gamble torment legs from kadala.

Answer (score 2):

Chest runs have been nerfed for quite some time. So no it's no longer worth running them. But they were pretty good.

The only thing about chest runs is that it's boring.